# What is the topological dual of $C_b(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, probability-theory, duality-theorems

Consider the Banach space $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ of continuous bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the sup-norm.

1) Do we know a precise description of its topological dual $C_b(\mathbb{R})^*$ ?

2) I was wondering what kind of relation has $C_b(\mathbb{R})^*$ with $C_c(\mathbb{R})^*$, the topological dual of the space $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions having compact support.

If $L\in C_b(\mathbb{R})^*$ then  there exists $C_L$ such that 
$|L(f)|\leq C_L\|f\|_\infty$ for any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$, and thus for all $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, so that $L\in C_c(\mathbb{R})^*$ and $ C_b(\mathbb{R})^*\subset C_c(\mathbb{R})^*$. Is that correct ? 
Then, can we find all the probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ into $C_b(\mathbb{R})^*$ ?

(In other worlds, is the "weak" topology for probability measures a weak* one ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the algebra $\mathcal A$ generated by the closed sets in $\mathbb R$.  The space of finitely-additive signed measures on $\mathcal A$, with variation norm, is the dual of $C_b(\mathbb R)$.

The top reference for this and many other interesting topics: Gillman & Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Functions*.  Note $\mathbb R$ is metrizable, so the "zero sets" in the book are just the closed sets.

Another model for the dual: Let $\beta\mathbb R$ be the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb R$, so that $C_b(\mathbb R)$ is naturally identified with $C(\beta \mathbb R)$.  Then utilize your knowledge for the dual of $C(K)$ where $K$ is compact Hausdorff.

Comment: Thanks. I dont see how do you identify $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ and $C(\beta \mathbb{R})$. For example, what is the image of a continuous function $f$ such that $f=1$ on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $f=2$ on $[1,+\infty)$ under such identification ?

Comment: According to the definition of $\beta \mathbb R$, any bounded continuous function on $\mathbb R$ has a unique extension to a bounded continuous function on $\beta \mathbb R$.  But in your case it is very simple, since all points of $\beta\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb R$ belong either to $\beta (-\infty -1]$ or to $\beta [1,+\infty)$.

Comment: I understand, I was mixing "Stone-Cech" and "one-point" compactification ... Thanks again

Comment: So does this means that Riesz representation theorem holds for the space $C_b(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: Riesz representation therorem: To get a countably additive measure, you need to use $\beta \mathbb R$, not merely $\mathbb R$ itself.  Or, as I said  in my answer, you could use a finitely-additive measure.

Comment: my question is If I have a linear map $T: C_b(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)\to C_b(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ then can I say $T^*: M(\mathbb R)\to M(\mathbb R)$?, where $M(\mathbb R)$ is the space of measures on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Countably additive measures on $\mathbb R$ ... no.  Countably additive measures on $\beta \mathbb R$ ... yes.

Answer (score 6):

The space $C^b(\mathbb R)$ is a commutative C*-algebra, hence by the Gelfand-Naimark theorem it is *-isomorphic to some $C(K)$ space ($K$ is the spectrum of this algebra and the *-isomorphism is just the Gelfand transform). The dual of a $C(K)$ space is described by the Riesz-Kakutani theorem as the space of all regular Borel measures on $K$.

EDIT: In this case, the spectrum of $C^b(\mathbb{R})$ is just $\beta(\mathbb{R})$ which can be seen directly using basic properties of the Gelfand transform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I unfortunately don't really know such a technology ...