# Specific function in $C(\mathbb{R})^*$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Consider the following function
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{x^r}.
$$
**Question**: for what real values of $r$ is this in $C(\mathbb{R}^+)^*$, the dual to the Banach space of continuous bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$. My guess
is $r<1$.

**Reasoning**: As long as $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$, then the linear mapping
$$
L_f:C(\mathbb{R}^+)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\;\;L_f(g)\equiv\int_0^\infty fg dx
$$
is continuous since
$$
\left|L_f(g)\right|\leq \sup_{\mathbb{R}^+}\left(|g|\right)\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)}.
$$

**Context**: I need to find the point spectrum of the adjoint of a linear operator defined on $C(\mathbb{R}^+)$. Functions similar to $f(x)$ come up. I need to determine which ones are in $C(\mathbb{R}^+)^*$.

**References**: I did look several places. In particular, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81836/what-is-the-topological-dual-of-c-b-mathbbr), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89274/the-dual-space-of-cx-x-is-noncompact-metric-space). None of what I looked at gave me concrete enough information (for my level of understanding) to make sure what I am saying is true.

**Simpler problem?**: Perhaps it makes it simpler for certain people to think on the whole line and consider  the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{|x|^r}
$$
on $C(\mathbb{R})^*$ instead of $C(\mathbb{R}^+)^*$.

Comment: Your guess is right.  When $r < 1$ then you have $f \in L^1$ and so $L_f$ is a continuous linear functional as you note.  When $r \ge 1$ then by considering the constant function $g=1$, we see that $L_f$ isn't even defined on all of $C(\mathbb{R}^+)$ and so can't possibly define a continuous linear functional.  Is there some particular part you have doubts about?

Comment: Hey, thanks. My only doubts came from me not feeling confident with the math used to describe the dual, thinking that my concrete example might have something wrong.